# Set Media Element source in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, media

I am trying to dynamically set a video .mv4 file as the source for my media element in my windows 8 app.

```
   var x = new MediaElement { Source = new Uri("ms-appx:/Assets/vid1.mv4") };

        this.DefaultViewModel["Video"] = x;
```

I use this code in my XAML cs file, in an attempt to bind it to the Medai element set up in the XAML page

```
<Paragraph Margin="0 40 0 0" LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight">
                                        <InlineUIContainer>
                                            <MediaElement x:Name="media" 
                                             Source="{Binding Video}" 
                                            Width="500" Height="300" AutoPlay="True" />
                                            </InlineUIContainer>
                                    </Paragraph>
```

But this doesn't work. However if I set the source directly in the media element on the XAML page `Source="Assets/vid1.m4v"`, it plays fine.

How do I set a video in C# for binding into a XAML windows 8 app page?

Comment: I'm not sure if our situations are identical but I'm having the same problem. I can set an "ms-appdata:/local/..." formatted string in Xaml MediaElement Source property and I can also create a Uri using this string and set the MediaElement Source property to it there -- both work fine, binding doesn't. But I also noticed something interesting when using the binding approach and putting a breakpoint in the codebehind Load event for the MediaElement. I then examined sender (i.e. MediaElement) Source property and it then had a "file:///..." format. In that case the MediaElement control would be d

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
var x = new MediaElement { Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/vid1.mv4") };
```

Answer (score 2):

`<MediaElement Source="{Binding Url}" />` will not work. You need to use `ContentControl`. Check out the below given code.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Video}" />
```

```
var x = new MediaElement { AutoPlay = true };
x.Loaded += MediaElement_Loaded;

private async void MediaElement_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var file = await KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.GetFileAsync(await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/vid1.mv4"));
    var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
    x.SetSource(stream, file.FileType);
    DataContext = x;
}
```

From: [Binding MediaElement to a ViewModel in a Windows 8 Store App](http://weblogs.asp.net/jdanforth/archive/2012/12/14/binding-mediaelement-to-a-viewmodel-in-a-windows-8-store-app.aspx)